# fatal error: opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp: No such file or directory opencv and GPU installation

Tags: gpu, nvidia, opencv3.0, opticalflow

the package I am trying to install is in the below link 
https://github.com/wanglimin/dense_flow

```
  (cv) -group-1-3p16:~/dense_flow$ sudo make 
    Scanning dependencies of target denseFlow_gpu
    [ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/denseFlow_gpu.dir/denseFlow_gpu.cpp.o
    /home/vinsent_research/dense_flow/denseFlow_gpu.cpp:4:31: fatal error: opencv2/gpu/gpu.hpp: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
    CMakeFiles/denseFlow_gpu.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/denseFlow_gpu.dir/denseFlow_gpu.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/denseFlow_gpu.dir/denseFlow_gpu.cpp.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/denseFlow_gpu.dir/all' failed
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/denseFlow_gpu.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
Not sure how to resolve this issue, I have installed opencv 3.4.1 on ubuntu 18, the installation was successfull, followed these post 

[https://github.com/VinACE/Install-TensorFlow-OpenCV-GPU-Ubuntu-17.10][2] 


my cmake 

    sudo cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -DPYTHON2_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python2 \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.4.1/modules \
        -D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
        -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
        -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/g++-5 \
        -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-5 \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

[the ubuntu opencv 3.4.1 install what i have followed](http://%20%20http://%20https://github.com/VinACE/Install-TensorFlow-OpenCV-GPU-Ubuntu-17.10)

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: No I  am using docker images, Not sure if the install will go smooth now..